# How do I make all of my @RequestMapping as @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()") by default?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, least-privilege

I’d like to apply the [Principle of Least Privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) in my endpoints by requiring all of them to be authenticated, unless stated otherwise at the method-level (so I don’t need to duplicate pathes from my controllers in a `SecurityFilterChain`).

Ideally, I’d want all of them to behave as if they were annotated by `@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")` by default, while still being able to override this by explicitly specifying a `@PreAuthorize` (or other annotations like `@PermitAll`). Of course, it can be achieved by annotating the `@Controller`s themselves like the following, but you can still forget to annotate one, which is the reason why I’d like a more global solution:

```java
@RestController
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping("/test")
    @PreAuthorize("permitAll()")
    public void test() {}
}
```

I tried following the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/method-security.html#request-vs-method) that says:

> It’s important to remember that when you use annotation-based Method Security, then unannotated methods are not secured. To protect against this, declare [a catch-all authorization rule](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/authorize-http-requests.html#activate-request-security) in your [HttpSecurity](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#jc-httpsecurity) instance.

So I kept [Spring Boot’s default `SecurityFilterChain`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/8bb60eef026fc8787b5ac763bcb9c532f3fcb5f9/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/security/servlet/SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration.java#L58) which does `http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())` like in the doc:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests.anyRequest().authenticated());
    http.formLogin(withDefaults());
    http.httpBasic(withDefaults());
    return http.build();
}
```

Then I tried using `@PreAuthorize("permitAll()")` on some endpoints to override it, with no success: as described in [my issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/14371) on the subject, `SecurityFilterChain` rules are evaluated before `@PreAuthorize`, so they can’t be overridden by it.

I tried using [custom method security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/method-security.html#custom-authorization-managers) (with a custom `SecurityFilterChain` identical to Spring Boot's but with the catch-all line `http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())` commented out) as advised in the issue, like this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests.anyRequest().authenticated());
        http.formLogin(withDefaults());
        http.httpBasic(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Role(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE)
    Advisor preAuthorize() {
        return AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.preAuthorize(AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager.authenticated());
    }
}
```

with no success, since [`AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.preAuthorize` only applies to `@PreAuthorize`-annotated methods](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/af2d210ccb62a00374983ff276e1a16e5773b130/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authorization/method/AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.java#L99):

```java
public static AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor preAuthorize(
        PreAuthorizeAuthorizationManager authorizationManager) {
    AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor interceptor = new AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor(
            AuthorizationMethodPointcuts.forAnnotations(PreAuthorize.class), authorizationManager);
    interceptor.setOrder(AuthorizationInterceptorsOrder.PRE_AUTHORIZE.getOrder());
    return interceptor;
}
```

(and indeed it does work if I annotate the `@Controller` with `@PreAuthorize("")`)

I tried creating my own `AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor`, but to no avail either for now, since I don't really understand how that internal machinery works.

Comment: Can you share any of the code from what you've tried so far? Also, please clarify what you mean by "I tried using custom method security as advised in the issue, with no succes, since AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.preAuthorize only applies to @PreAuthorize-annotated methods." Do you mean that you tried this in addition to a catch-all rule? Please share code.

Comment: Sorry, your clarification did not clear it up for me, because "without the catch-all..." seems to contradict "since AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.preAuthorize only applies to @PreAuthorize-annotated methods." You seem to imply you do not have any authorization rules, so this likely means you are using the Spring Security default (`anyRequest().denyAll()`), but I can't be sure without code.

Comment: Done, I hope it’s clearer this time, sorry. Are you sure the default is `denyAll()`? If I remove everything in my `securityFilterChain` (but the `return http.build();` of course) I still get a 200 when trying to access my `test` endpoint (with or without `@PreAuthorize("permitAll()")` on it)

Comment: When you register a filter chain with no authorization rules, it doesn't register the `AuthorizationFilter` at all which is why you see a 200. This is why the docs suggest a catch-all rule. So you're right that it doesn't default to `denyAll()` in that case. It will only do that if you register other rules without an `anyRequest()` catch-all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your additional explanation and code snippets (which were useful for clarity), I can share one possible way to achieve your goal.

---

**WARNING:** Before doing so, I will once again reiterate that multiple layers of defense are always better than implementing something like this, because we can be assured that when one layer fails (due to a variety of reasons including misconfiguration), another layer is in place for baseline protection.

---

To achieve a "fallback" with only method-security, we can target all methods in the application that have the `RequestMapping` annotation, including as a meta-annotation (e.g. `@GetMapping`, `@PostMapping`, etc.). We can rely on the fact that the existing `PreAuthorizeAuthorizationManager` abstains (returns null) when no `PreAuthorize` annotation is found on the method/class.

**NOTE:** The major downside of this approach is that endpoints available through (for example) servlet mappings are not protected, so it is still possible to have endpoints that are not protected. A robust set of [functional tests for security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/test/index.html) will be required to ensure you can have confidence here.

The following is an example security configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = false)
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin(withDefaults());
        http.httpBasic(withDefaults());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        // ...
    }

    @Bean
    @Role(BeanDefinition.ROLE_INFRASTRUCTURE)
    static Advisor preAuthorize() {
        var pointcut = forAnnotation(RequestMapping.class);
        var authorizationManager = new CatchAllPreAuthorizeAuthorizationManager();
        var interceptor = new AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor(pointcut,
            authorizationManager);
        interceptor.setOrder(AuthorizationInterceptorsOrder.PRE_AUTHORIZE.getOrder());

        return interceptor;
    }

    private static Pointcut forAnnotation(Class<? extends Annotation> annotation) {
        return Pointcuts.union(new AnnotationMatchingPointcut(null, annotation, true),
            new AnnotationMatchingPointcut(annotation, true));
    }

    static class CatchAllPreAuthorizeAuthorizationManager
            implements AuthorizationManager<MethodInvocation> {

        private final AuthorizationManager<MethodInvocation> delegate =
            new PreAuthorizeAuthorizationManager();

        private final AuthorizationManager<MethodInvocation> fallback =
            AuthenticatedAuthorizationManager.authenticated();

        @Override
        public AuthorizationDecision check(Supplier<Authentication> authentication,
                MethodInvocation object) {

            var authorizationDecision = this.delegate.check(authentication, object);
            if (authorizationDecision == null) {
                // PreAuthorizeAuthorizationManager abstained due to no PreAuthorize
                // annotation, so apply fallback.
                authorizationDecision = this.fallback.check(authentication, object);
            }

            return authorizationDecision;
        }

    }

}
```

Another minor note, in testing with this setup there are other gotchas and caveats that pop up, for example the default Spring Boot `/error` endpoint provided by `BasicErrorController` and issues with `favicon.ico` requests that return a 404. More configuration may be required to get things fully working with your setup.

Comment: What is the recommended way to handle that `/error` in the general case (since Spring Boot's default SecurityFilterChain would block it too)? The usual "whitelist" in a custom SecurityFilterChain?

Comment: That depends on your requirements. By default, the `/error` page requires authentication as it contains privileged information. You may consider creating your own error page or endpoint, since you can't annotate Spring Boot's default error controller. Again, I can't stress enough that this solution has holes and gotchas and I don't recommend it in general.